# Trouble using indexed arrays with preg_replace() PHP

Tags: php, arrays, preg-match

First time i post here and hope somebody will be able to help me.

I have a file whos numbering starts at 610 and goes on to 1019. I want to use PHP's preg_match() function to start the numbering from 0 and go on till 410.

Here is some code i've been working on. But i cant get the function to replace the numbers. I don't know why and i don't get any errors.

```
<?php

$string = "610 611 612 613 614 615 616 617"; //this isnt the actual file but will do. The actual file is more complicated. This is just a test string.

$patterns = array();
for ($i=610; $i<1020; $i++) {
    $patterns[$i] = '/$i/';
}

$replacements = array();
for ($j=1; $j<410; $j++) {
    $replacements[$j] = '\r\n' . $j;
}

$newText = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string);
echo $newText;

?>
```

I used Example #2 form http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php as reference.

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: Can you describe what's not working for you?  Inputs, outputs and expected outputs would help...

Comment: Don't use single quotes on `'/$i/'` and `'\r\n'`. Use double quotes instead. See the difference here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: I don't know, but I find it odd to be using regular expressions for this situation.

Comment: @Bolt It's not that odd. It's tricky to use `str_replace()` because of word boundaries that might be different. That said I would approach this problem some other way (if I knew what it was)

Comment: And you don't want to use `/20/` as it will also replace `120`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This won't do?

```
implode(" ", range(0, 410))
```

It seems odd that you want to change them "in place".

Comment: beaten to it :) exactly what I was thinking.

Comment: You missed this comment: `//this isnt the actual file but will do. The actual file is more complicated. This is just a test string.`

Comment: @Null No, I read it. But it doesn't provide any insight. If anything, it could make the regex solution less desirable because if text followed, it could contain some of the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Your "patterns" array looks like this:

```
$patterns (
   610 => '/$i/',
   611 => '/$i/',
...
}
```

You need to use double quotes on line 7:

```
$patterns[$i] = "/$i/";
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother with regular expressions for such a simple case...  Simply use str_replace.  It'll be faster, and equivalent to your present code...

```
$patterns = array();
for ($i=610; $i<1020; $i++) {
    $patterns[] = $i;
}

$replacements = array();
for ($j=1; $j<410; $j++) {
    $replacements[] = '\r\n' . $j;
}

$string = str_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string);
```

Now, you'd still need to use preg_replace if the patterns are more complicated (such as only searching for the start of the line, etc)...  But for such a simple pattern, it's not worth it (IMHO)...

Comment: `'\r\n'` won't be a newline. `str_replace()` is also not really appropriate for this (think word boundaries)

Comment: I know that.  But he said he was dealing with files.  So I assumed that he knew it won't be a new line and wanted to put a literal `\r\n` in there...  I wasn't sure if that was an error or explicit, so I just went with what (s)he provided...

Comment: Yeah, it would help if the OP provided actual input and expected output files